# Optimize multiple self-JOINs or redesign DB?

Tags: mysql, database-design, join, self-join

I'm looking for advice on either optimizing multiple self-joins, or a better table/DB design.

One of the tables looks as follows (relevant cols only):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CountryData (
  countryDataID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dataID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DataSources (dataID),
  dataCode VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  countryID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Countries (countryID),
  year INT NOT NULL ,
  data DEC(20,4) NULL,
  INDEX countryDataYear (dataID, countryID, year));
```

The `data` column has values for a few hundred indicators, 90 countries, and 30 years for ~1mn rows total. A standard query requires selecting N indicators for a particular year and C countries, yielding a CxN table for 90 rows max.

With all values in a single column, self-joins seemed like the way to go. So I have experimented with various suggestions to speed those up, including indexing and creating new (temp) tables. At 9 self-joins, the query takes a little under 1 min. Beyond that, it spins forever.

The new table from where the self-joins take place has only about 1,000 rows, indexed on what seem to be the relevant variables - creation takes about 0.5 sec:

```
CREATE TABLE Growth
    SELECT dataID, countryID, year, data
    FROM CountryData
    WHERE dataID > 522 AND year = 2017;

CREATE INDEX growth_ix 
    ON Growth (dataID, countryID);
```

The `SELECT` query then arranges up to XX indicators in the results table, with XX unfortunately <10:

```
SELECT 
    Countries.countryName AS Country,   
    em01.em,
    em02.em,
    em03.em
    ...
    emX.em
FROM    
    (SELECT
        em1.data AS em,
        em1.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em1
    WHERE
    em1.dataID = 523) as em01
    JOIN 
    (SELECT
        em2.data AS em,
        em2.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em2
    WHERE
    em2.dataID = 524) as em02
    USING (countryID)
    JOIN
    (SELECT
        em3.data AS em,
        em3.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em3
    WHERE
    em3.dataID = 525) as em03
    USING (countryID)
    ...
    JOIN
    (SELECT
        emX.data AS em,
        emX.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em5
    WHERE
    emX.dataID = 527) as emXX
    USING (countryID)
    JOIN Countries 
    USING (countryID)
```

I'd actually like to retrieve a few more variables, plus potentially join other tables. Now I'm wondering whether there's a way to run this more efficiently, or whether I should take an altogether different approach, such as using wide tables with indicators in different columns to avoid self-joins.

Comment: This probably belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

Is the `dataID` unique for a given `countryID` and `year` or can a `dataID` appear multiple times with different values?  If it is unique, you may be able to try something like this?

```
SELECT countryID, year
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN dataID = 523 THEN data ELSE NULL END ) AS em0 
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN dataID = 524 THEN data ELSE NULL END ) AS em1 
    ,...
FROM CountryData
GROUP BY countryID, year
```